# please help! how do I make a bootable usb pen drive to install my windows 10 iso on 15.04?

Tags: boot, usb, 15.04, usb-drive

How do I make a bootable usb pen drive to install my windows 10 iso on 15.04? 
I'd like detailed instructions with commands and  or possibly a link.

Comment: Close voters: How is this not about Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods.

1. If you have wine preinstalled:

   Download Rufus (you need Wine two run it.
   then select your iso file and the usb device. the rest is easy
2. Wine not required:

   Install Winusb. Open a terminal windows (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

   Paste the following commands one by one:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
   sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/colingille-freshlight-trusty.list"
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install winusb
   ```

   Now, choose From a disk image(iso)

   select your file

   Then select the target device

   Click install

Comment: How do you make USB devices usable under Wine?

Answer (score 0):

[UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) will do

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

Or you could try a [bit-by-bit](https://serverfault.com/questions/6714/how-to-make-windows-7-usb-flash-install-media-from-linux/167060#167060) copy.

Comment: I wonder why the developers say it won't do: "UNetbootin allows you to create bootable Live USB drives for Ubuntu and other Linux distributions without burning a CD."